# semantic error: unable to find local 'set32'

Tags: docker, fedora, systemtap

when i try to run my Docker image to translate .stp file to .ko file, a error appear

```
semantic error: unable to find local 'set32', [man error::dwarf] dieoffset 0xbd5c37 in kernel, near pc 0xc1062e20 in __se_sys_sigpending kernel/signal.c (alternatives: $uset, $ret)): identifier '$set32' at /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/sysc_sigpending.stp:31:30
        source:     set = @choose_defined($set, $set32)
                                                ^
    in expansion of macro: operator '@alternate' at /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/choose_defined.stpm:3:57
        source:     ( @defined(@value_if_defined) ? (@value_if_defined) : (@alternate) )
                                                                           ^
    in expansion of macro: operator '@choose_defined' at /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/sysc_sigpending.stp:31:8
        source:     set = @choose_defined($set, $set32)
                          ^

semantic error: unable to find local 'iov', [man error::dwarf] dieoffset 0x1f63320 in kernel, near pc 0xc11a5430 in __se_sys_vmsplice fs/splice.c (alternatives: $uiov, $fd, $ret, $flags, $nr_segs)): identifier '$iov' at /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/sysc_vmsplice.stp:39:8
        source:     iov = $iov
                          ^

semantic error: unable to find local 'iov', [man error::dwarf] dieoffset 0x1f63320 in kernel, near pc 0xc11a5430 in __se_sys_vmsplice fs/splice.c (alternatives: $uiov, $fd, $ret, $flags, $nr_segs)): identifier '$iov' at :39:8
        source:     iov = $iov
                          ^

Pass 2: analyzed script: 883 probes, 1643 functions, 102 embeds, 80 globals using 283744virt/279964res/6720shr/274484data kb, in 60540usr/14740sys/27034real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

I really dơn't know exactly what that is. Can someone help me? (I used Fedora 30 image Docker and write script to support translate)